# Visual C++ 6.0 Read Arguments of Application

Tags: visual-c++, arguments, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I have a sample code to read the arguments of applications using Visual Basic 6.0.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim Argument as String
   Argument = Command$
End Sub
```

How to implement the code in visual c++ 6.0? Please help me :)

Comment: They are passed to the `main()` function. [Read this for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

Comment: I do not see the main function in the code, there is only dialogue and inter-related code such as VB6, how to make it in the dialogue?

Comment: Ok. Then you can use the [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) function instead.